# Informix SQL error - Why won't this UPDATE statement work?

Tags: sql, error-handling, decimal, informix, sql-update

Using IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 10.00.FC9

The error I'm getting is:

`1226: Decimal or money value exceeds maximum precision.`

Normally, this makes perfect sense and I can fix the precision via `CAST`, but everything I try is still producing the same error.

I have three columns that I initially set to a constant of `0.00`.  After a few statements, I have updated two of these columns to positive decimals keeping the same precision.

When I try to multiply these two columns together to update the third column, I get the error above.

My update statement is: `UPDATE table SET col_3 = col_1*col_2;`

---

I've tried several things, but have had no luck in avoiding that error.

I tried setting the constant in `col_3` to `0.000000`.

I also tried updating using `CAST` on both the two sides of the multiplication and the final value:

`UPDATE table  SET col_3 = CAST((col_1) AS DECIMAL(6,2))*CAST((col_2) AS DECIMAL(6,2));`

`UPDATE table SET col_3 = CAST((col_1*col_2) AS DECIMAL(6,2));`

Any combination of these attempts always results in the same error.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here or doing wrong?

Comment: You know that IDS 10.00 is no longer supported by IBM, I presume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set the constant to `12.00`

I was missing the two places before the decimal